# Creating a form to show external API data

Tags: php, xml, wordpress, api, jquery

I am trying to create form that submits a query to the education.com api and returns results that I can control the markup and styling of. I have created the form below but it takes me to the external xml doc.

```
<form action="http://api.education.com/service/service.php"  method="get">
<input name="f" value="schoolSearch" type="hidden"/><br />
<input name="Resf" value="xml" type="hidden"/><br />
<input name="sn" value="sf" type="hidden"/><br />
<input name="v" value="4" type="hidden"/><br />
<input name="key" value="bd23bb5cb91e37c39282f6bf75d56fb9" type="hidden"/><br />
<input name="zip" type="text"/><br />
<input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Ideally I'd like to create a robust form that allows user to query the api and show the results styled as the rest of my site is. Thanks for any help!

Comment: you should be looking at curl

Answer (score 0):

Use curl to retrieve the response and save to a variable. You'll then use either DOM or simpleXmlElement to parse the return back into the format you want.